# How to display the variable in its true format in python?

Tags: python, utf-8

There are some Chinese characters in the variables and when I want to check it in python interactive environment, the Chinese characters can not be displayed in right way. For example , `\x01\u672c\u7530`

So how to set the python to display it in right way without using any print command ?

```
>>> a
[(u'5770718203630666668', ['0', '', u'wh10033', u'car.m.autohome.com.cn', u'http://car.m.autohome.com.cn/price/result-10_15-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-1.html', u'\u672c\u7530', u'1', '0.0000', '0.0000', u'\x01\u672c\u7530', u'\u672c\u7530', u'http://car.m.autohome.com.cn/price/result-10_15-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-1.html\x01\u672c\u7530', u'\x01http://car.m.autohome.com.cn/price/result-10_15-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-1.html\x01\u672c\u7530', u'\x01http://car.m.autohome.com.cn/price/result-10_15-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-1.html'])]
```

Comment: You are echoing the whole data structure, and contents are always shown as `repr()` output. Print individual elements or write your own representation function to concatenate the contents.

Comment: In other words, this is working **exactly as designed**. You can't 'set' a different configuration.

Comment: `print(a)` should do the job.